# Getting 400 error when trying to forgot password in strapi

Tags: vue.js, strapi

I am trying to use strapi forgot password and i have the frondend in vue js. When I a trying to send request for the forgot password it throws me an error of 400.

```
<template>
<form @submit.prevent="onForgetPassword">
   <label for="name">your email</label>
    <input type="email" class="from-input" placeholder="Enter Your Email..." v-model="email"/>
    <button type="submit" class="form-btn">reset password</button>
 </form>
</template>



data() {
    return {
      email: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onForgetPassword() {
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:1337/auth/forgot-password", {
          email: this.email
        })
        .then(response => {
          // Handle success.
          console.log("Your user received an email");
        })
        .catch(error => {
          // Handle error.
          console.log("An error occurred:", error);
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: try providing the `url:
      'http:/localhost:1337/admin/plugins/users-permissions/auth/reset-password'` with email

Comment: I have added the url with email still getting POST http://localhost:1337/auth/forgot-password 401 (Unauthorized)